# mercurial: "abort: could not symlink"

Tags: mercurial

I'm trying to do an `hg merge` but am getting the message `abort: could not symlink to '/path/one': File exists: /path/two`

Both /path/one and /path/two exist and are directories.  I don't want to get rid of either of them.

Comment: Could you provide more details? Like what are you trying to merge? In one of the branches you have a symbolic link and in the other you have a directory? ``path/one`` and ``path/two`` are under version control on both heads?

Comment: @RudyMatela - sorry, this question is now so old I can't remember the exact situation that caused it.  I think to work around it, I had to rename one or both directories and merge them back in by hand.  But thanks for trying - necromancy badge?